# afterUpdate listener in typeorm does not listen to updates on @UpdateDateColumn - postgres DB

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs-typeorm

I'm working on a functionality, where in I have an entity called 'Employee' with a few columns like first name, last name, DOB, etc. and two columns:createdAt and updatedAt defined with @CreateDateColumn and @UpdateDateColumn respectively.

My requirement is that, whenever an update operation is performed on this entity, I should be logging the column name that was updated, along with the old and new value that it holds.

I'm performing the update on Employee table using queryRunner.manager.save()

To track the changes,
I'm making use of the entity subscribers 'afterUpdate' event.

Now on performing an update, for e.g. When I change the Name, my Employee entity is correctly updating the name as well as the 'updatedAt' field to current timestamp in DB
However,my 'afterUpdate' listener is only logging the 'name' column with its old and new values.
Its not logging the updatedAt column.

Can anyone please help me understand what's possibly going wrong here?

**Entity definition:**
...All columns (first name, etc.)
@UpdateDateColumn({name:'updated_at',type:'timestamp',nullable:true})
updatedAt:Date;

**Subscriber code:**

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class EmployeeSubscriber implements 
EntitySubscriberInterface<EmployeeEntity> {
constructor()
{}
listenTo() {
return EmployeeEntity;
}

afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<EmployeeEnitity>){
const {updatedColumns, dataBaseEntity,entity}=event;
updatedColumns.forEach(({propertyName})=>{
//Get the updated column name and old and new values
//col_name = propertyName;
//oldVal= databaseEntity[propertyName as keyof EmployeeEntity] as string,
//newVal= entity?.[propertyName as keyof EmployeeEntity] as string,
})
}
}
```

I tried using different save operations (via repository, queryRunner, manager), but it didn't work.
Official docs say the event is triggered only on save operation.

If I manually pass the date to updatedAt field, then I am able to get the field within the event handler, but I don't think that's the right approach as manual intervention should not be needed for @UpdateDateColumn

Comment: Can you put your subscriber code here?

Comment: Added the subscriber code. The 'afterUpdate' listener is able to log/track the updates on all other columns in Employee table except the updatedAt column defined with @UpdateDateColumn decorator